# Why doesn't the MILP produce a solution when its obviously solvable?

Tags: python, gurobi, pulp

I'm solving a MILP in a Python script with PuLP and the Gurobi solver and varying parameters.

A sensitivity analysis is done with a 'for' loop, changing a parameter at every run. The first runs are with 'worst case' parameters (very low efficiency generator and very bad insulation material), and gradually the parameters get improved while looping through the MILP. At some point, when parameters are set in a way that a solution should be found quite quickly, Gurobipy does not seem to find a solution. This is the log:

```
Changed value of parameter TimeLimit to 300.0
Prev: 1e+100  Min: 0.0  Max: 1e+100  Default: 1e+100
Optimize a model with 8640 rows, 10080 columns and 20158 nonzeros
Variable types: 8640 continuous, 1440 integer (0 binary)
Coefficient statistics:

Matrix range     [2e-05, 4e+04]
Objective range  [1e+03, 1e+03]
Bounds range     [7e-01, 4e+04]
RHS range        [1e-02, 3e+04]

Presolve removed 7319 rows and 7331 columns
Presolve time: 0.03s
Presolved: 1321 rows, 2749 columns, 4069 nonzeros
Variable types: 1320 continuous, 1429 integer (1429 binary)

Root relaxation: objective 4.910087e+05, 679 iterations, 0.01 seconds

Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

 0     0 491008.698    0   11          - 491008.698      -     -    0s
0     0 491008.698    0   11          - 491008.698      -     -    0s
0     2 491008.698    0   11          - 491008.698      -     -    0s
30429 24907 491680.652  942    3          - 491011.160      -   1.0    5s
73520 66861 491679.428  958    3          - 491011.996      -   1.0   10s
123770 116802 491762.182 1241    2          - 491012.439      -   1.0   15s
174010 165706 491896.963 1266    2          - 491012.636      -   1.0   20s
221580 212357 491234.860 1144    5          - 491012.931      -   1.0   25s
270004 259925 491187.818  904    5          - 491013.203      -   1.0   30s
322655 311334 491807.797 1254    2          - 491013.349      -   1.0   35s
379633 367554 491194.198  941    5          - 491013.571      -   1.0   40s
434035 420930 494029.008 1375    1          - 491013.695      -   1.0   45s
490442 476293 494016.622 1354    1          - 491013.851      -   1.0   50s
544923 529662 491203.097  990    5          - 491013.947      -   1.0   55s
597268 581228 492312.463 1253    2          - 491014.018      -   1.0   60s
650478 633331 491093.453  383    5          - 491014.133      -   1.0   65s
703246 685374 491755.974 1241    2          - 491014.188      -   1.0   70s
756675 737356 491069.420  272    6          - 491014.250      -   1.0   75s
811974 791502 491560.902 1235    3          - 491014.308      -   1.0   80s
866893 845452 491112.986  497    5          - 491014.345      -   1.0   85s
923793 901357 494014.134 1348    1          - 491014.390      -   1.0   90s
981961 958448 492971.305 1266    2          - 491014.435      -   1.0   95s
1039971 1015276 491545.502 1216    4          - 491014.502      -   1.0  100s
1097780 1071899 491171.468  818    5          - 491014.527      -   1.0  105s
1154447 1127328 491108.438  461    5          - 491014.591      -   1.0  110s
1212776 1184651 491024.147   57    6          - 491014.622      -   1.0  115s
1272535 1243171 495190.479 1266    2          - 491014.643      -   1.0  120s
1332126 1301674 491549.733 1228    3          - 491014.668      -   1.0  125s
1392772 1361287 491549.544 1219    3          - 491014.694      -   1.0  130s
1452380 1419870 491754.309 1237    2          - 491014.717      -   1.0  135s
1511070 1477572 491229.746 1131    5          - 491014.735      -   1.0  140s
1569783 1535126 491130.785  587    5          - 491014.764      -   1.0  145s
1628729 1593010 494026.669 1368    1          - 491014.775      -   1.0  150s
1687841 1651373 493189.023 1264    2          - 491014.810      -   1.0  155s
1747707 1709984 491548.263 1223    3          - 491014.841      -   1.0  160s
1807627 1768777 491160.795  755    5          - 491014.876      -   1.0  165s
1865730 1825486 494030.045 1379    1          - 491014.899      -   1.0  170s
1925615 1884356 494028.562 1374    1          - 491014.923      -   1.0  175s
1984204 1941827 491847.402 1115    2          - 491014.933      -   1.0  180s
2044016 2000572 491244.304 1210    5          - 491014.970      -   1.0  185s
2102125 2057622 491174.413  828    5          - 491014.989      -   1.0  190s
2161393 2115829 491115.089  532    5          - 491015.017      -   1.0  195s
2220721 2174168 491086.511  348    6          - 491015.041      -   1.0  200s
2281194 2233610 infeasible 1433               - 491015.048      -   1.0  205s
2341496 2292542 492824.696 1262    2          - 491015.069      -   1.0  210s
2399836 2349837 491548.142 1224    3          - 491015.084      -   1.0  215s
2459295 2408276 491178.869  853    5          - 491015.088      -   1.0  220s
2519203 2467098 491112.995  488    5          - 491015.106      -   1.0     225s
2578654 2525514 491069.711  270    6          - 491015.123      -   1.0  230s
2636111 2582093 491762.206 1250    2          - 491015.139      -   1.0  235s
2695962 2640805 491237.559 1152    5          - 491015.146      -   1.0  240s
2755319 2699171 491156.897  797    6          - 491015.161      -   1.0  245s
2813620 2756371 491024.109   43    7          - 491015.182      -   1.0  250s
2872810 2814527 492309.743 1255    2          - 491015.185      -   1.0  255s
2932550 2873227 492180.501 1255    2          - 491015.202      -   1.0  260s
2991586 2931246 491244.162 1207    5          - 491015.217      -   1.0  265s
3050385 2988872 491196.181  952    5          - 491015.228      -   1.0  270s
3110478 3047787 491127.746  560    5          - 491015.247      -   1.0  275s
3169730 3105844 491109.579  525    6          - 491015.266      -   1.0  280s
3229972 3165019 494029.916 1376    1          - 491015.276      -   1.0  285s
3289639 3223661 491861.516 1173    2          - 491015.293      -   1.0  290s
3349653 3282631 491862.419 1185    2          - 491015.305      -   1.0  295s

Explored 3409667 nodes (3506772 simplex iterations) in 300.02 seconds
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 0

Time limit reached
Best objective -, best bound 4.910153206264e+05, gap -
('Gurobi status=', 9)
```

I've increased the maximum solving time to 300s (more takes up to much RAM and the programm gets terminated at some point) and played around with parameters (worse parameter settings find a solution!) but nothing seems to work.  What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by inserting "None" for maximum solving time and inserting a loose maximal gap.